# How to convert a SQL query to Spring JPA query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a SQL query like this:
`"Select UIProfileID from UserTable where UPPER(UserID) = UPPER('?1')"`.

I want to convert it to Spring JPA.
I want to write `getUIProfileId()` and return Integer. But I don't know how to implement. Because User table doesn't have `UIProfileId` column that it was joined from `UIProfileTable` table. Please help me solve it. 
Currently, I have tables:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "UserTable")
public class User {

  @Column(name = "UserID", length = 32, nullable = false)
  @Id
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "DomainID", nullable = false)
  private Domain domain;

  @Column(name = "Password", length = 32, nullable = false)
  private String password;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "UIProfileID", nullable = false)
  private UIProfile uiProfile;

  @Column(name = "ResPerpage", nullable = false)
  private Integer resperpage;

  @Column(name = "DefaultTab")
  private Integer defaulttab;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "AdminProfile")
  private AdminProfiles adminProfile;

  @Column(name = "LanguageId")
  private Integer languageId;
}
```

**UIProfile.java**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "UIProfileTable")
public class UIProfile implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "UIProfileID", length = 11, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "UIProfileName", length = 32, nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.uiProfile")
  private List<UIProfileTopLevel> topLevels;
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, String> {

  Optional<User> findOne(String name);

  @Query("Select UIProfileID from User where UPPER(UserID) = UPPER('admin')")
  Integer getUIProfileId();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@Query("SELECT u.uiProfile.id from User u where UPPER(u.name)=UPPER('admin')")
Integer getUIProfileId();
```

Here `User` is the domain class name and `u` is the reference of User. with `u` we will access User's field **NOT** the column name which are specified with `@Column or @JoinColumn` Ex : `@JoinColumn(name = "UIProfileID", nullable = false)`.

Comment: Hi, Ajit Soman. It will be returning UIProfile object cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: @ Ajit Soman. I want to get Id of  UIProfileTable @Column(name = "UIProfileID", length = 11, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;.

Comment: @ Ajit Soman I think it will return a UIProfile why it arises List here.

Comment: Ok i have updated my answer . i have'nt noticed @ManyToOne Mapping

Comment: Hi, Ajit Soman UIProfile is the entity class. You were SELECT u.uiProfile it will return UIProfile. My problem is how to we get Id of UIProfileID column of   UIProfileTable table from User entity(UserTable table)

Comment: I thought by returning `UIProfile` object from query you will be able to get id by executing UIProfile's getId() method. Ok not an issue .. i have updated my final answer.

Comment: I don't know why @Query("SELECT u.uiProfile.id from User u where UPPER(u.name)=UPPER('?1')")
Integer getUIProfileId("admin"); It doesn't work and exception to be thrown "Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist"

Comment: I solved by reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters